# Проблемы с отправкой форм (ajax)

Tags: ajax, form

Прошу помощи в следующем вопросе.

Есть 2 формы ("Заказать звонок" и "Написать нам"), под них есть скрипт, который выполняет отправку без перезагрузки страницы. Если использовать скрипт отдельно под конкретную форму - все работает, но было бы неплохо, если бы скрипт выполнялся для всех форм в зависимости от аргументов, переданных ему. В js я не силен, пытался своими силами ковырнуть - не вышло. Ниже предоставляю две формы, скрипт и php. Прошу подсказать, как можно реализовать сие. Заранее благодарю!

HTML формы:

```
<form id="fcallback" class="contact-form" action="">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col form-field col x-50">
  <input name="name" id="name" placeholder="Имя" type="text" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col form-field col x-50">
  <input name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Телефон" type="tel" required>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-field col x-100 align-center">
  <div id="messegeResult"><button class="boot" id="button" type="button" onclick="AjaxFormRequest('messegeResult', 'fcallback', 'send2.php')">Перезвонить мне</button></div>
  </div>
  </form>

    <form id="fcontact" class="anketa" action=''>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Имя" type="text" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="mail" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input id="comm" name="comm" placeholder="Сообщение..." type="text" required>
        <div id="messegeResult"><div class="bnt_center"><button class="boot" id="button" type="button" onclick="AjaxFormRequest('messegeResult', 'fcontact', 'send.php')">Отправить</button></div>
    </form>
```

AJAX:

```html
 function AjaxFormRequest(result_id,form_id,url) {
 jQuery.ajax({
 url: url,
 type: "POST",
 dataType: "html",
 data: jQuery("#"+form_id).serialize(),
 success: function(response) {
 document.getElementById(result_id).innerHTML = response;
 },
 error: function(response) {
 document.getElementById(result_id).innerHTML = "<b>При отправке данных возникла ошибка</b>";
 }
 });

 $(':input','#'+form_id)
 .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
 .val('')
 .removeAttr('checked')
 .removeAttr('selected');
 }
```

PHP Callback (для второй формы используются аналогичный обработчик с соответствующими форме пар-ми)

```html
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to = "petest@ro.ru";
    $subject = "Callback с Premium Escort";
    $message = '<span style="font-weight:bold;color:#ff6600;font-size:18px;"><i>Заказ обратного звонка с сайта Premium Escort</i> </span><br><br>
    Имя: <span style="font-weight:bold;color:#339900;">'.$_POST['name'].'</span><br>
    Телефон: <span style="font-weight:bold;color:#339900;"> '.$_POST['phone'].'</span>';
    $headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n";
    $headers .= "From: <agent@premuim-escort.com>\r\n";
    $result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  
if ($result){
    echo "<font style="color: black"><center><b>Спасибо, мы скоро перезвоним!</b></center></font>";
}
}
?>
```

И сразу же, попутно, еще такой вопросец, можно ли error: function(response) подтягивать таким же образом, как и success ? вытягивать результат с php файла? На ум приходит только следующее, но думаю, это заклинание не сработает:

Ajax:

```
success, error: function(response) {
 document.getElementById(result_id).innerHTML = response;
```

а в PHP:

```
if ($result){
        echo "<font style="color: black"><center><b>Спасибо, мы скоро перезвоним!</b></center></font>";
    }
    else {
    }
        echo "<font style="color: black"><center><b>При отправке произошла ошибка!</b></center></font>";

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос.

Нужно было всего лишь задать для каждой формы уникальные идентификаторы.